# unable to install tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning

[image]

When I was trying to install tensorflow from `PyCharm` than, I got above error. I also tried in terminal

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

> Error:Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow**

Default version:
[image]

I just changed it by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485102/13146129)

I thought the question is belongs to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com)
But, I changed my mind by [reading the question](https://superuser.com/questions/241865/updating-python-on-ubuntu-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Wieland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4699/wieland) said in earlier [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640329/449077), there's no TensorFlow package in Python 3.9.

So, I felt awkward little bit. If there's no tensorflow package than how can I deal with data science and machine learning. I searched on DuckDuckGo little bit. I found a question [similar to this(completely same)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622401/tensorflow-installation-in-python-3-9-064-bit-and-pip-version-20-2-3). There's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66427197/13146129) which said `tf-nightly`(tf=TensorFlow) works in python3.9. [He said also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622401/tensorflow-installation-in-python-3-9-064-bit-and-pip-version-20-2-3#comment117434989_64627678). So, I tried

```
pip3 install tf-nightly
```

Hopefully, tensorflow is working now....

Comment: Is it working? I mean, it's great to post this as an answer so people know it's an option, but it would be even better to confirm in the answer if it actually worked for you.

Comment: Also, as I am sure you are aware, you could use Python 3.8 and be able to do data science just fine.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes! I could. But, newer version works better than older ones. So, I chose Python 3.9.2 completely new one...

Comment: @DavidZ ~You can accept your own answer tomorrow~ this is what I am getting that's why I didn't mark it as an answer...

Comment: Newer may mean new features, but I strongly disagree that newer means a software works better. People continued to use Windows XP longer than they should just to avoid “upgrading” to the hot mess of Windows Vista.

Comment: @Istiak sure but that's separate from what my comment was talking about. Your answer ends with "Hopefully, tensorflow is working now...." and I'm suggesting you replace that with a confirmation of whether it is or isn't actually working.

Comment: @DavidZ Oh! Yes It's working....

Answer (score 5):

TensorFlow only provides packages for Python 3.6, Python 3.7 and Python 3.8: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files (at the moment, this lists files for Python versions cp36, cp37, cp38). You are using Python 3.9, for which no TensorFlow package is available.

In addition, https://www.tensorflow.org/install says

> TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:
>
> ```
> Python 3.6–3.8
> ```

Comment: I got the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640366/449077)